# gem make_flaggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on implementing a like button, following the tutorial on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG-kCSx0taU&feature=related, which says i should install gem 'make_flaggable', :git => 'git://github.com/cavneb/make_flaggable.git', when enter this in my gem file and run 'bundle install' i get the error below, i then run bundle update and i get another error. 
Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":   In Gemfile:
    make_flaggable (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 3.2.1) ruby depends on
      activerecord (3.2.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the so nice fork which you can get from [github.com/jaimeiniesta/make_flaggable](https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/make_flaggable). 
 Most probably this will get you out from this error.

Thanks for [jaimeiniesta](https://github.com/jaimeiniesta) for the fork...

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'make_flaggable', :git => 'git://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable.git'
```

Worked for me.